# Need help in database query for contest winners

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm creating a web application where the user will be able to participate in a contest and based on their rank, the user will be rewarded.

(table name contest)

```
id    |   contest_name   |   status
------------------------------------
1     |   Test Contest   |   active
```

(table participants)

```
id    |    user_id   | contest_id   | score   | time_taken  
----------------------------------------------------------
1     |    123       |     1        |  10     |   2332  --> in milliseconds
```

My contest table prize distribution (table name price_distribution)

```
id   |  contest_id  |  rank_start  | rank_end  | price
-------------------------------------------------------
1    |    1         |     1         |   10     |   50
-------------------------------------------------------
2    |    1         |     11        |   20     |   25
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Meaning if all the users that rank between 1 to 10, they will get 50 points and rank between 11-20, 20 points so on.

I've used this query to get all  the list of users in the contest with their rank.

```
SELECT participants.score,
       participants.time_taken, 
       contest.name as contest_name, 
       user.name as username,
       user.image as userimage, 
       FIND_IN_SET( participants.score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( participants.score ORDER BY participants.score DESC, participants.time_taken ASC ) 
                                         FROM participants )) AS rank
FROM participants 
LEFT JOIN contest 
ON participants.contest_id = contest.id 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = participants.user_id 
WHERE participants.contest_id = '1' 
ORDER BY participants.score DESC, participants.time_taken ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

The above query results is this

```
score   |  time_taken  | contest_name  | username  | userimage  | rank  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
10      |   2356       |  test_contest |  abc      |  image     | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above query only lists the user based on rank and does nothing else.
I want to reward the user based on rank.. How to achieve this query.

I want to know the query which when executed will reward the user based on their rank and will take the value from the prize distribution table.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table `price_distribution` based on the user's score:

```
SELECT participants.score,
       participants.time_taken, 
       contest.name as contest_name, 
       user.name as username,
       user.image as userimage, 
       FIND_IN_SET( participants.score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( participants.score ORDER BY participants.score DESC, participants.time_taken ASC ) 
                                         FROM participants )) AS rank,
       pd.price
FROM participants 
LEFT JOIN contest ON participants.contest_id = contest.id 
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = participants.user_id 
LEFT JOIN price_distribution pd 
ON participants.contest_id = pd.contest_id and participants.score BETWEEN pd.rank_start AND pd.rank_end
WHERE participants.contest_id = '1' 
ORDER BY participants.score DESC, participants.time_taken ASC 
LIMIT 50
```